# Crashes my application when I take number from TextView

Tags: java, android

I do a calculator and I have the next problem. When I write '-2' then click button minus and write '2' then I must have '-4' but my application crashes.
That's my application:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRFp2.png)

The main(large) numbers are TextView. The TextView in MainActivity.java was written as variable 'display'. When user clicks on button equal (=) will call the next method:

```
// make result of two numbers
public void onEqual (View v) {
   display.setText(makeResult()); // set TextView result of computation
}
```

And the method 'makeResult' that will search for two numbers in 'display' and will do an operation with them (+, -, / or *). In addition to this there is a variable 'operator' in my code. The variable saves the current operator that user set that we can use it in the future to make calculation of two numbers.. so this is my code of that method

```
// make result of two numbers
private String makeResult () {
    double one; // one number
    double two; // two number
    double result; // result of two numbers

    String dis = display.getText().toString(); // take text from TextView for more comfortable(manipulation)

    one = Double.parseDouble(dis.substring(0, dis.indexOf(operator) - 1)); // take the first number from the start of the string and until an index of 'operator' (we don't take 'operator')
    two = Double.parseDouble(dis.substring(dis.indexOf(operator) + 2, dis.length())); // take the second number after 'operator' until the end of the string

    switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            result = one + two;
            break;

        case "-":
            result = one - two;
            break;

        case "/":
            result = one / two;
            break;

        case "x":
            result = one * two;
            break;

        default:
            result = 0;
    }

    operator = "";

    return new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(result); // do format of result ( 5.0 -> 5 )
}
```

Additionality, every 'operator' has two space after and before 'operator' ( + ) for more comfortable and etc.

So, why does my application crash when I set the next calculation: (-2 - 2)?
Help me pls. I don't understand how I can do it. 
P.s If something I'm sorry for my English because I'm from Russia)
P.s(2) Original of this article in Russian source [here](https://toster.ru/q/563734).

Error code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
        at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
        at com.example.danilochagov.calc_3000.MainActivity.makeResult(MainActivity.java:48)
        at com.example.danilochagov.calc_3000.MainActivity.onEqual(MainActivity.java:185)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where 185 line is the string where in method 'onEqual' calls the method 'makeResult'. And 48 string is the place where method 'makeResult' do it

```
   one = dis.substring(0, dis.indexOf(operator) - 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint & debugging? Or just checking the logs/console for a stacktrace?

Comment: how about declaring `operator`?

Comment: If your app crashes then there is a corresponding entry (stack trace) in Logcat. Please add this to your question

Comment: @dustytrash check the stacktrace out

Comment: @0X0nosugar check the stacktrace out

Comment: @MartinZeitler my code has the next

       private static String operator = "";

Comment: In your example "-2 - 2" there are two places where "-" is used. indexOf("-") will give you the *index of the first occurence* of "-". So in your case: 0. Maybe that's why your substring expression does not work

Comment: thanks, but I've solved my problem so. I need to do 

    one = dis.substring(0, dis.indexOf(" "));

Because when user is writing -2 - 2 that app has '-' in the start of string and number won't be valid

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times where (at least in my opinion) it is easier to just use regex.

```
public String makeResult(String expression) {
    double result = solve(expression);
    return FORMAT.format(result);
}

public static final DecimalFormat FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");
public static final Pattern EXPRESSION = Pattern.compile(
    "([+-]?\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d*)" // first number
        + "\\s*([+-xX/])\\s*" // operator 
        + "([+-]?\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d*)" // second number
);

public double solve(String expression) {
    Matcher m = EXPRESSION.matcher(expression);
    if (m.matches()) {
        double lhs = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        double rhs = Double.parseDouble(m.group(3));

        switch (m.group(2)) {
            case "x":
            case "X": return lhs * rhs;
            case "/": return lhs / rhs;
            case "+": return lhs + rhs;
            case "-": return lhs - rhs;
        }
    }
    return 0; // or throw exception
}
```

In the pattern, `([+-]?\\s*\\d+\\.?\\d*)` means a number optionally followed by a decimal part and optionally preceded by a sign. The `\\s*` sprinkled in there mark places where spaces are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer to resolve my problem with my methods.